# Lookup item in an ArrayList and output

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, interface

Hi there I am trying to output items from an arrayList if the users input matches the itemNumber in the ArrayList.. I am using an and these are the override methods.

the implemented interface methods:

```
package Purchase;

import java.util.*;
public class Items implements recordItem {

String description;


ArrayList<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<Items>();
public static Items newItems = new Items();
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to replace the  **return "does not exist";** and then add the object that does not exist to the list?

Comment: @Kiresays no, my issue is that it is returing "does not exist" when I am wanting it to return the item description from the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem is here:

```
this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
this.description = description;
this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
this.sort = sort;

Items theItems = new Items();
itemList.add(theItems);
```

Your are adding an empty "Items" to the list.

This will work:

```
Items theItems = new Items();

theItems.itemNumber = itemNumber;
theItems.description = description;
theItems.unitPrice = unitPrice;
theItems.sort = sort;

itemList.add(theItems);
```

And please never use static instances like

```
public static Items newItems = new Items();
```

in your entity classes.